# rails redirect_to incorrectly sends me to put from update route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this as my update route:

```
def update
   params.require(:player_id)
   params.require(:id)

   @draft = Draft.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to draft_draftees_path(@draft.id)
end
```

Whenever it does the redirect it tries to do a put instead of a get to the index route and so it says:
No route matches [PUT] "/drafts/28/draftees"

I don't know why it's trying to do a put. Is it because it's coming from an update function? I'm using React on this page so does that have something to do with it? How can I redirect to that index route within the update route? Please help!

[UPDATE] Here's my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/users' => 'users#create'

  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :users
  resources :drafts do
    resources :teams
    resources :draftees
    resources :players
  end
end
```

Comment: The redirect_to will just send a 302 header to the browser.  The browser will do a GET. You should look into it further.  Probably something else.

Comment: Please include your `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
redirect_to draft_draftees_path(@draft.id)
```

to

```
redirect_to draft_draftees_path(@draft)
```

as it will pass the complete draft instance to the draftees path.
The put request is formed because you are passing @draft.id to the draftees path that results in a request like this

```
/drafts/:draft_id/draftees/:id
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you are using nested resources then there may be 2 possibilities of redirection.

1. Redirection to **/drafts/:draft_id/draftees** which will show all draftees for a particular draft.
2. Redirection to **/drafts/:draft_id/draftees/:id** which shows the updated draftee.

In order to achieve second one you need to redirect as:

```
redirect_to(draft_draftees_path(@draftee.draft, @draftee)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I want to achieve the first one but as a get route. It's trying to do it as a put

Comment: `redirect_to draft_draftees_path(@draft)` should do what you are expecting, if it still does a put request, then try doing a CURL request, maybe the problem is due to React.

Comment: when I did the curl request it looks like it worked because it gave me the html for the page I am trying to redirect to. Does that mean it's a React issue?